# Crontab no encuentra comandos de bash script en Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, cron, crontab

estoy usando un bash script para limpiar la memoria cache y swap que manualmente funciona correctamente, pero puesto en `CRONTAB` **no funciona porque no encuentra los comandos** `swapoff` `sysctl` y  `swapon`.

**Contenido de limpiar.sh**

```
#limpiar.sh
#!/bin/bash

#La siguiente línea es necesaria si piensa ejecutar este script con CRON
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/snap/bin:/root/bin

echo "<---------------------------------------------------------->"
echo "<---------------------------------------------------------->"

echo "Comprobando estado de memoria"
free -h
echo "OK - Comprobación completada"
echo "<---------------------------------------------------------->"

sleep 1s; echo “Limpieza de memoria cache y swap“;
echo "<---------------------------------------------------------->"

sleep 1s; echo "Deshabilitando Swap"
swapoff -a
echo "OK - Swap deshabilitado"
echo "<---------------------------------------------------------->"

sleep 2s; echo "Liberando pagecaches, dentries e inodes"
sync;sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3;sync
echo "OK - Server liberado"
echo "<---------------------------------------------------------->"

sleep 3s; echo "Habilitando la Swap"
swapon -a
echo "OK - Swap habilitado"
echo "<---------------------------------------------------------->"

sleep 2s; free -h
echo ".....TODO CORRECTO....."
echo "<---------------------------------------------------------->"
echo "<---------------------------------------------------------->"
```

**Contenido de $PATH del usuario ROOT:**
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/root/bin`

**Línea del CRONTAB:**

`*/5 * * * * /home/ubuntu/limpiar.sh 2> /home/ubuntu/limpiar.log`

NOTA: El CRONTAB es del usuario root

**Contenido de errores de limpiar.log**

```
/home/ubuntu/limpiar.sh: 15: swapoff: not found
/home/ubuntu/limpiar.sh: 20: sysctl: not found
/home/ubuntu/limpiar.sh: 25: swapon: not found
```

Uso Ubuntu 20.04

Crontab funciona correctamente con todos los demás scripts.

Cualquier otra información que se requiera me lo informan, yo ya probé agregando la ruta `:/root/bin` al PATH por las dudas que fuera ese el problema, pero no se solucionó.

***EDITO***

**SOLUCION DEFINITIVA PARA CRON:**
Ya he publicado la solución más abajo pero faltaba algo que lo advertí más adelante.

Noté que la ejecución con CRON no era igual a la ejecutada manualmente.
Con CRON limpiaba de 3 a 5MB y no limpiaba la swap, mientras que manual limpiaba +500MB + swap.

Se trataba de un problema de rutas (PATH)!

Eso lo pude averiguar agregando como 3ra línea del script el comando `echo $PATH` y al ejecutarse con CRON devolvió solamente esto: `/usr/bin:/bin`

Como vi que faltaban rutas de root, lo que hice fue editar el script y agregar todas las rutas faltantes con el comando `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/snap/bin:/root/bin`

Ahora sí el bash script funciona correctamente como si lo estuviera haciendo de forma manual! : )

Answer (score 1):

he encontrado los motivos y la solución de porque `CRONTAB` no encuentra estos comandos.

Parece ser que estos comandos deben ejecutarse en un `CRONTAB` de sistema (no de usuario).
O sea que no se puede incluir este script editando el crontab del usuario root como lo hacemos habitualmente con crontab -e

Les copio lo que encontré y cito la fuente al final:

**Crontab de sistema**
El crontab de sistema se utiliza generalmente cuando se requiere que una tarea se ejecute con privilegios de administrador (root). La definición es igual a la de un crontab de usuario con la excepción de que se debe incluir el campo "usuario". Es posible editar directamente el archivo /etc/crontab aunque es más prolijo agregar una definición dentro del directorio `/etc/cron.d/`, el cual sirve para almacenar cronjobs de sistema para diferentes usuarios. Por ejemplo podemos crear el archivo `/etc/cron.d/limpiar01` con el siguiente contenido:

`*/5 * * * * root /home/ubuntu/limpiar.sh 2>&1 >> /home/ubuntu/limpiar.log`

Notar que luego de la definición del día de la semana se ha agregado el nombre de usuario con el que se ejecutará el proceso que lleve a cabo al tarea programada, en este caso "root".

Cada vez que definimos una nueva tarea programada dentro del directorio `/etc/cron.d/` el servicio cron la levanta automáticamente. No es necesario reiniciar el servicio.

**NOTA:** La sintaxis del crontab del sistema NO se puede aplicar al crontab del usuario root (cuando se edita el crontab de este usuario con crontab -e) debido a que el campo "usuario" (root) no es requerido para este crontab y dará el siguiente error:  "/bin/sh: root: command not found".

Fuente: https://www.linuxito.com/gnu-linux/nivel-alto/245-resolver-errores-en-cron

Comment: Los comandos fueron encontrados y el script se ejecuta sin errores, sin embargo la limpieza que se hace a través de ```CRON``` es mínima! Solo libera aprox 5MB y no libera la swap, cuando lo ejecuto manual me libera +500MB y sí libera la swap. Alguien sabe porque sucede esto ?

Comment: **EDITO: Solución:** Leí que podía ser un problema de rutas, lo comprobé con un ```echo $PATH``` puesto en el script ejecutado con ```CRON``` y devolvió solo: ```/usr/bin:/bin```. Por ese motivo agregué como 2da línea del script: ```export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/root/bin``` y ahora funciona de forma correcta como si lo hiciera manual! Alguna ruta está demás, solo agregué el PATH completo de root porque no sabía cual de las rutas alojaba todos los comandos que no se ejecutaban correctamente.